# Is there a way to remap keys to change between tabs like Sublime Text/Atom and Browsers?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I was searching for some way to change Netbeans tabs behavior to act like Sublime Text or Google Chrome, but found nothing so far.

In sublime, you can change tabs using the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>number</kbd> (Or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>number</kbd> in OSX), as seen in the following image:

[image: Shortcut key example]

So my question is: Does anyone knows a way to do this in Netbeans ? I still love the IDE, but this feature is really important to me, because make me more productive.